# Pulley/winch knot for holding up heavy punching bag

Tags: mounting, load-bearing, rope-knots

I currently have a heavy bag mount I built from `4x4` posts to hold up a 100lbs punching bag. [It currently has a nice swivel bracket holding it up](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00076ZE0I), which has been working great so far. The only problem here is that sometimes I need the extra space in the garage, and need to take the bag down.

Is there a safe hitch or knot I could use for mounting, hanging, and taking down the bag? I tried using [a clove hitch](http://www.animatedknots.com/cloveend/) to hold on to the bag, and then [a trucker's hitch](http://www.animatedknots.com/truckers/index.php?Categ=boating&LogoImage=LogoGrog.jpg&Website=www.animatedknots.com) to raise the bag up into position, and some half-hitches to hold it in place. This doesn't work as well as I'd hoped, as the trucker's hitch sometimes loosens when I hit the bag really hard and send it swinging, so I'm trying to find a better alternative.

Is there a better set of knots/hitches I could use with some 750lbs type IV paracord, or some stronger rope that would fit into the mounting bracket's loop? This current system would be great if the hitch wasn't loosening and posing a safety risk, as it's a real pain to get up on a step ladder and do a one-armed military press of a 100lbs bag to mount it. I've nearly crushed my fingertips twice while doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: If you could use a couple of pulleys it would make lifting the bag easier, and put less tension on the end of the rope when tying it off.

Comment: I have mine attached to 4 links of chain. When I need to remove it I lift it off the swivels hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One setup which would be easy to setup and take down would be a combination of a ceiling mounted punching bag carabiner, swivel pulley, and boat cleat.

Start by bolting the carabiner to the ceiling. A solid wooden beam would be perfect for this. After that, mount the boat hitch to a solid vertical surface such as a wall or vertical beam.

Then attach the swivel pulley to the carabiner, and tie one end of a piece of rope to the punching bag. You can use an anchor bend knot to attach the rope to the metal ring. Fish the other end of the rope through the pulley and lift the bag into place with the rope.

Tie the rope off on the boat cleat by using a cleat hitch. This setup will easily allow you to take the bag down and set it up without using any tools. The cleat and knots are designed to hold a boat, so a punching bag would be no problem.

### Swivel Pulley

[image: Swivel pulley]

### Cleat Hitch & Knot

[image: Cleat Hitch Knot]

### Punching bag carabiner

[image: Carabiner]

### Anchor Bend Knot

[image: Anchor Bend]

The cleat can be purchased at any marine supply store, or boat dealer. Just about every cleat on the market will be strong enough to support a heavy bag.

There are two main styles of cleats. There are ones which have 2 screw holes which go through the center, and others with 4 holes. The ones with the 2 center holes will take more abuse before failing than the 4 holed varieties.

Comment: Be careful that your anchor point, pulley, and mounting hardware (carabiner) are strong enough. When you use a mechanical advantage like that to lift, you double the load on the anchor point and hardware (100 lbs. for the bag + 100 lbs. of you pulling on it... so 200 lb. rating minimum).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using any equipment that is rated less than 4 times the dead weight of the bag itself, which would be 400 lbs. I personally would use a minimum of 1/2" climbing rope or dock line for this. Rope like this is rated from ~5000 - ~8000 pounds. You don't want the rope to fray or stretch very much. Be sure to use adequately sized fasteners. With the amount of weight involved, I would be more concerned with the fasteners failing by either pulling out or breaking off. Most carabiners that are rated for climbing will work. These also screw together to prevent them from opening up.

Comment: Thank you. I like this a lot. I'll likely add a bag spring between the carabiner and the pulley to reduce noise and vibrations, but this is awesome. Thanks again!

Comment: Could you please fix the dead imgur link under "Cleat Hitch & Knot"?

Comment: @bcsteeve fixed.

Comment: @Jimmy Fix-it, I thought that a single pulley provides no mechanical advantage and multiple pulleys do not, if they are not "ganged" in the manner of a block and tackle. A single pulley provides for direction change only. If the "puller" weighs 85 pounds and the load is 100 lbs, the puller will not move the load, hence no mech. advantage. Even with a block and tackle providing 2:1 advantage, the load on the ceiling hook cannot exceed the lifted load, ex: 100 lbs. The bag won't get heavier because an assist is in use.

Comment: You are partially correct, a single pulley attached to a load provides no mechanical advantage on the pulling end; I wrote incorrectly. However, your other point is incorrect ("the load on the ceiling hook cannot exceed the lifted load"), the load on the anchor is exactly double the weight of what you are lifting, plus some for anchor friction.

Comment: Actually, I believe that whether or not the load on the anchor is doubled depends on the direction change angle, I was assuming straight vertical pull. At least this is how I was taught.

Comment: I've been thinking about this setup, trying to envision it for my needs.  When you are using the bag, it sways.  in all directions, really.  If the rope is anchored to the wall and slung through the pulley and down to the bag... what happens when the bag starts swaying?  Is that not a problem?  Does the Caribbean at the top provide great enough degrees of freedom?  Does the rope stay on the pulley track?  Can the pulley handle this kind of force that it probably wasn't designed for (side to side)?

Answer (score 2):

Look to the rock climbers.

For attaching, a **[figure-8 followthrough](http://www.animatedknots.com/fig8follow/)** is a serious no-slip knot (and you can tie the tail in for extra insurance.) I pull out my instruction sheet for that knot when tying a static line onto a tree to keep me from falling off a roof. I might not need the sheet, but I am betting my life on the knot, so I make sure I haven't forgotten. Not associated with sites linked, just some decent images that came up in searching.

[image: Figure 8 followthorugh]

For hanging, a pulley would be far preferable, and then a cleat (look to the boat folks - wind a figure-8 and flip the second loop so it holds itself) to hold the line. Evidently called a [cleat hitch.](http://www.netknots.com/rope_knots/cleat-hitch/)[image: cleat hitch]

There probably are clever rope tricks as well, but hardware will be simpler and also easier on the rope (clever rope tricks can be somewhat wearing)